# Storing access token obtained through client credentials oauth2 flow

Tags: rest, security, oauth-2.0, authorization

In the context of machine to machine oauth2 token secured communication I want to know how should I store the access token on a backend application for further use (until the token expires) ?

The access token is obtained through the client_credentials oauth2 flow from the authorization server and it is used for making authorized calls on the resource server (in the client's behalf)

What is the best practice for storing the access token on the client so that it can be used to make further calls to the resource server and not asking for a new token for each call ?

[image]

Comment: this suggests your client does have a safe way to store the `client_secret`: then you may use that same mechanism for storing the access token

Comment: yes, the client is a Java application so it can store the client_secret in a properties file

Answer (score 1):

Storing on client side isn't the best way to start. But if you want to do this, you should add the token to a secure cookie with a CSRF token too, so the access token can't be extracted in other forms. Also, it's a good idea to set a timeout if the token isn't being used for an amount of time that you think it's ok.